# JS как отследить, почему не загрузилось на странице? Оптимизация загрузки страниц

Tags: javascript, nginx, оптимизация-сайтов, php-nginx

Добрий день! На сервере NGINX+PHP-FPM работает сайт. Анализирую время загрузки сайта по Google Analitics. Беру какую-то одну страницу и вижу - 300 раз страница грузилась в пределах 1-4 секунды и один раз - 60сек или даже больше, при чем длинная загрузка не тогда, когда она берется из бекенда, а когда уже, по идеи, берет готовую згенерированную страницу. И такое случается на многих страницах сайта периодически.

По сайту  - движок Друпал 7, для кеширования страниц используется модуль boost, который при первом запросе генерирует готовую страницу, а дальше она уже выдается nginx без поднятия бэкенда (без запуска php, mysql). Для кеширования бекенда используется мемкеш (раньше использовал варниш, но проблема была также)

Проверял логи сервера - проблем не обнаружил.

Хочу сделать на js какой-то скрипт, который будет, например, срабатывать на 20сек. и отправлять на сервер, какие возникли ошибки при загрузке и что не загрузилось, или что долго грузилось. Для этого я могу добавить такой код

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        ga('send', .........)
    }
}, 20000);
```

Но чем заполнить функцию ga? можно ли получить инфу о скорости соединения клиента? как получить логи запросов загрузки страницы?

Подскажите, есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение или инструменты для этого?

Возможно есть инструменты или готовый js для интеграции с Google Analitics?

Возможно есть другие варианты отслеживания причин медленной загрузки страницы?

Буду благодарен за любую идею или подсказку, куда копать.

Вопрос важен для многих потому, что Google Analitics использует выборку из медленных загрузок и показывает её как среднее время, а среднее время, как пишут в гугл будет влиять на выдачу в поиске.

**P.S.** В результате я хочу понять: причина медленной загрузки - это сбои на сервере или проблема в плохом интернете клиента.

Comment: JS вам в этом может и не помочь. Ведь что бы он начал работать, надо что бы он загрузился. Здесь поможет лог всех запросов.

Comment: если встроить js в основной код, то я могу например на 20 сек проверить загрузилась страница или нет (document.readyState !== "complete") и если не загрузилась ещё, передать событие в google analitics. Как я могу получить на js лог всех запросов, а также желательно знатьхоть какую то информацию о скорости интернета пользователя - может всё-таки проблема в этом....

Comment: А если у вас тормозит на этапе первоначальной загрузки документа (например, тупит boost), то js тут не поможет. Проверить скорость интернета косвенно вы сможете тоже только после полной загрузки всех ваших скриптов. Копайте в сторону логирования всех http запросов.